# Why can't assign attribute with {attr:value} in __setattr__?

Tags: python-3.x, class

We can assign attribute with {attr:value}:

```
class Room():
    pass
```

Create an instance of the class `Room`:

```
r=Room()
```

Assign attribute `name`:

```
r.__dict__ = {'name':'r1'}
r.name
'r1'
```

Rewrite the `Room` class:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        self.__dict__ = {attr:value}
```

Create a instance:

```
r=Room('r1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __setattr__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __setattr__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __setattr__
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I can fix it with `self.__dict__[attr]=value`,but i want to know why can't assign attribute inside `__setattr__` in the format `self.__dict__ = {attr:value}`?

Comment: Even if this worked, it would forget any old attributes every time you set a new one - your code attempts to completely replace the old `__dict__` and any attribute data it held.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `__dict__` is an attribute, so `self.__dict__ = ...` will call `__setattr__`, which causes an infinite recursion. As is indicated by the error.

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__setattr__#object.__setattr__) states:

> If `__setattr__()` wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should call the base class method with the same name, for example, `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

So then your code becomes:

```
...
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        object.__setattr__(self, '__dict__', {attr:value})
```

My advice is: don't do mess around with `__setattr__` (in real code) unless you really have to and know what you are doing (and the same for `__dict__`). There are often better ways to get what you want for actual code than using `__setattr__`.